# Как распарсить файл на Go?

Tags: алгоритм, парсер, golang

Как распарсить файл на Go 
Имеется файл с матрицей вида

```
3
1.01 1.02 6.3 ....... 5.343
2.04 1.03 3.3 ....... 5.343
...........................
...........................
2.3 ................... 4.5
```

Где верхняя строка это размерность матрицы, а все остальные строчки это матрицы. 
Нужно распарсить в двойной массив вида var a [][]Float64

Comment: совсем никаких идей нет?

Comment: Размерность три, а итоговая матрица 5x5? Приведите хотя бы нормальный пример файла и что из него должно получиться.

Comment: Можете начать [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49385380/read-two-files-simultsneously-value-by-value-using-regexp/49388753#49388753). Это не в точности ваша задача, но очень похоже. Особенно интересный вариант от peterSO. Удачи.

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятны ваши входные данные, но если предполагается, что они корректны и выглядят как-то так

```
3
1.0 2.1 3.4
2.1 3.2 3.3
1.5 3.2 1.1
```

то решение в лоб выглядит примерно так

```
file, err := os.Open("file")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer file.Close()

scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
scanner.Split(bufio.ScanLines)

// get size
scanner.Scan()
N, err := strconv.Atoi(scanner.Text())
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

// init matrix
matrix := make([][]float64, N)
for i := 0; i < N; i++ {
    matrix[i] = make([]float64, 0, N)
}

// scan values from the file
i := 0
for scanner.Scan() {
    ar := strings.Split(scanner.Text(), " ")
    for _, a := range ar {
        val, err := strconv.ParseFloat(a, 64)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        matrix[i] = append(matrix[i], val)
    }
    i++
}

// print matrix
for _, line := range matrix {
    fmt.Println(line)
}
```